# how to get percentiles using mutate_at?

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider this simple example

```
> tibble(var1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
+        boo1 = c(1,2,3,4,5))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
   var1  boo1
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     2     2
3     3     3
4     4     4
5     5     5
```

Here I want to get the current value expressed as a percentage using `ecdf`. This is expected to work but it does not.

```
> tibble(var1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
+        boo1 = c(1,2,3,4,5)) %>% 
+   mutate_at(vars(contains('boo')), 
+             .funs = funs(ecdf(.)(.)))
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: 'x' and 'y' lengths differ.
```

Instead, this works

```
> tibble(var1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
+        boo1 = c(1,2,3,4,5)) %>% mutate(percentile = ecdf(boo1)(boo1))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
   var1  boo1 percentile
  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1     1        0.2
2     2     2        0.4
3     3     3        0.6
4     4     4        0.8
5     5     5        1
```

What is the issue here? Thanks!

Comment: can u use `map` i.e. `map_df(df1, ~ ecdf(.x)(.x))` i.e. you can select the columns of interest and do the 
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two alternatives would be

```
ecdfEval <- function(x) ecdf(x)(x)
tbl %>% mutate_at(vars(contains('boo')), ecdfEval)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#    var1  boo1
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1   0.2
# 2     2   0.4
# 3     3   0.6
# 4     4   0.8
# 5     5   1
```

and

```
tbl %>% mutate_at(vars(contains('boo')), funs(do.call(ecdf(.), list(.))))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#    var1  boo1
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1   0.2
# 2     2   0.4
# 3     3   0.6
# 4     4   0.8
# 5     5   1
```

It is indeed strange that your approach didn't work, seems like using `.` in nested functions is a problem.

---

**Edit** (better option): It seems like it may be more about `funs` than `mutate_at` since, as @Nate noticed, we can indeed use simply

```
tbl %>% mutate_at(vars(contains('boo')), .funs = ~ecdf(.)(.))
```

(See @Nate's comment below for more details.)

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ, I guess someone else will provide a better explanation soon. Might be a bug, and also might be a significantly more complex case to implement, and hence not done yet.

Comment: you can also use `.funs = ~ecdf(.)(.)`.

Comment: @Nate, that's clearly much better, not sure how I missed it!

Comment: it looks like the `~` causes it to be processed by the newer `rlang::as_function()` (and all of the other rlang eval tools) while `funs()` is still being handled by the older dplyr predecessors. I'm guessing that the older dplyr tools didn't have all of the flexibility that rlang has now, so you couldn't get too fancy with multiple `.`, like `ecdf(.)(.)`